# Get SPListItems based on contribute permissions, programmatically

Tags: permissions, splistitem, groups

I have a problem in getting the list items the current logged user has contribute rights on.
I have this scenario:

List A has read permissions for anonymous access.

1. Group 1- Has contribute rights on the List A
2. Group B- Has contribute rights on some SPListItems of the List A
3. Group C- Has contribute rights on some others SPListItems of the List A
4. Group D- Has contribute rights on some others SPListItems of the List A

(I assigned item level permissions on the list items, using an event receiver)

Now I need to create an administration web part, where each user can view and manage items

So:

1. Users from group 1 should view and manage all items
2. Users from group B should view and manage items where they have contribute rights
3. Users from group C should view and manage items where they have contribute rights ect.

The problem is: How to query this list and get list items based on group permissions.

On way is to get all the list items and check for each item if the current user has contribute rights on that item. But this way causes bad performance..

Is there any other solution?

Comment: I would guess that having individual permission on item level you'd have to check each item. There's no "meta data navigation"-kind of workaround that I know of. Do you really need item level permission?